# How to send Android intent url

Tags: android, android-intent, unity-game-engine

So Im trying to send params from an intent to a Unity project.  Right now I click a link like "http://myurl.com/myfile.html?param1=xxx&param2=xxx",  it opens the app as intended and now Im trying to get those param values and send them to my app.  Even if its just getting that entire url is acceptable and I can parse in the app. Here is my manifest file with where Im defining the scheme.

```
<activity
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  android:launchMode="singleTask"
  android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale"
  android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
  android:exported="true">
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
  <intent-filter>
      <data android:scheme="http"
            android:host="myurl.com" 
            android:pathPrefix="/myfile.html" />
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I looked online and saw a UnitySendMessage but am unsure if I could use that or how to use it.

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("GameObjectName1", "MethodName1", "Message to send");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Handle Intent data in Android side.
2. Convert intent data to JSON,XML,using string.Join, or what can u
   parse in Android side
3. Use this function and send this data Android to Unity.

> UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("GameObjectName", "MethodName",
>   "YOUR_STRING_PARAMETRE"); GameObjectName : This gameobject must be
>   exist in your scene. MethodName : you have to attach c# component to
>   this gameObject. YOUR_STRING_PARAMETRE : Converted intent data

Example:

- Create GameObject in Scene with Name : "IntentHandlerGameObject"

Create this C# class:

```
public class IntentHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void SetIntentData(string intent)
    {
        Debug.Log(intent);
        //Now parse  Converted intent data  what u want.
    }
}
```

> UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("IntentHandlerGameObject",
>   "SetIntentData", "PARSED_INTENT_DATA");

- Add IntentHandler Component with using drag and drop on
  IntentHandlerGameObject.

  4. Parse your string intent data in Unity.

Comment: For some reason my onCreate doesn't fire when I override it,  I think your solution will work for what Im wanting to do but for some reason its not letting me get past the first step